# How to upsert with MongoDB array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to insert, update values in the MongoDB array.
My MongoDB version is 4.0.5.

Here is my collection :

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'array': [{
        'code': 'a'
    }, {
        'code': 'b'
    }]
}
```

I am trying to make some upsert queries to insert/update into an array but I don't found a good solution until then.

My filters are :

- `'id'` (to point the correct document)
- `'array.code'` (to point the correct array cell)

1. If the document exists in the collection but there is no cell with `'code': 'c'`

```
db.test.update({
        'id': 1
    }, {
        $set: {'array.$[elem].test':'ok'}
    }, {
        upsert: true,
        arrayFilters: [{'elem.code': 'c'}]
    }
)
```

I have no error but no upsert too.
I want to insert the element in the array like this :

```
// Desired result
{
    'id': 1,
    'array': [{
        'code': 'a'
    }, {
        'code': 'b'
    }, {
        'code': 'c'
        'test': 'ok'
    }]
}
```

2. If the document doesn't exist in the collection

```
db.test.update({
        'id': 3
    }, {
        $set: {'array.$[elem].test':'ok'}
    }, {
        upsert: true,
        arrayFilters: [{'elem.code': 'a'}]
    }
)
```

In that case, I have this error :

> `WriteError: The path 'array' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates., full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 2, 'errmsg': "The path 'array' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates."}`

I want to upsert a new document with elements of the query like this :

```
// Desired result
{
    'id': 3,
    'array': [{
        'code': 'a'
        'test': 'ok'
    }]
}
```

`upsert: true` in the query parameters doesn't seem to work with the array.
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The `upsert: true` applies to the document, i.e. you insert a new **document** if it does not exist. It does not apply to an element in an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upsert is not effective in the array, If you do update MongoDB version from 4.0.5 to 4.2 then you can able to use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

**Case 1:** If the document exists in the collection but there is no cell with `'code': 'c'`:

```
var id = 2;
var item = { code: "c", test: "ok" };
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/onXRciJlHk1)

**Case 2:** If the document doesn't exist in the collection:

```
var id = 3;
var item = { code: "a", test: "ok" };
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/45i6QEmzYNd)

- `$ifNull` to check if the field does not exist then return empty
- `$cond` to check if input `code` is in array

  - yes, then `$mep` to iterate loop of `array` and check condition if match then update other fields otherwise return an empty object
  - `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with updated fields
  - no, `$concatArrays` to concat current `array` with new item object

```
db.collection.update(
  { "id": id },
  [{
    $set: {
      array: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: [item.code, { $ifNull: ["$array.code", []] }]
          },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$array",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.code", "c"] }, item, {}]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $concatArrays: [{ $ifNull: ["$array", []] }, [item]]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  { upsert: true }
)
```