# How to update and overwrite elements in array of objects?

Tags: mongodb

Now i remove all dublicates with use $addToSet, $each for recursive add objects, need merge if id same and any field change, and add new if id not found:

```
await this._collection.updateOne(
                {id},
                {
                    $set: {
                        type: type || meetingFromMongo.type,
                        unreadMessagesCount: unreadMessagesCount || meetingFromMongo.unreadMessagesCount,
                    },
                    $addToSet: {
                        calls: {
                            $each: calls || [],
                        },
                        members: {
                            $each: members || [],
                        },
                        messages: {
                            $each: messages || []
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
```

Try find any method for this, but found only findAndUpdate, but idk how use him for my task

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upsert with MongoDB array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225868/how-to-upsert-with-mongodb-array)

Comment: i try this, thx u, give feed back after

Comment: @ray i can't update question, jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aocfwy4p/
I try this for mergeObjects