# Array update or add as new

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

**I just want to update array value with matching value or add as new**

**Schema**
*imgs : ["imgPath1" , "imgPath2" , "imgPath3" ]*

I tried with this code but not working

```
let userQuery = { "user.id": req.user.id, _id: themeID, "imgs.$" : result.Location };
let userTask = { $set: { "imgs.$" : req.body.path} };
let userOptions = { upsert: true, new: true }
doc = await Images.findOneAndUpdate(userQuery, userTask, userOptions);
```

**Error - MongoError: Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.**

Comment: Added error message @mandy8055

Comment: can you give an example scenario. maybe with a small input and output. maybe use https://mongoplayground.net/p/2a3f-yxAwnG as a starter

Comment: something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/G-kP7YBhTEP ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upsert with MongoDB array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225868/how-to-upsert-with-mongodb-array)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a specific element in the array based on a condition, you need to make sure that the condition in the query matches the specific element you want to update.

In your case, you are trying to update the element in the **"imgs"** array where the value is equal to result.Location. If there is no element in the array with that exact value, the update will fail.

To address this, you can consider using the **$elemMatch** operator in your query to ensure that the array element you are trying to update matches both the *user ID*, theme ID, and the specific value in the array.

You should try something similar to the example below :

```
let userQuery = {
  "user.id": req.user.id,
  _id: themeID,
  imgs: { $elemMatch: { $eq: result.Location } }
};

let userTask = {
  $set: { "imgs.$": req.body.path }
};

let userOptions = { upsert: true, new: true };

doc = await Images.findOneAndUpdate(userQuery, userTask, userOptions);
```

In this example, **$elemMatch** ensures that all conditions must be satisfied for an element in the array to be considered a match. Adjust the query conditions based on your specific use case.

---

**edited :**
The following code should work $addToSet is used to add the new element to the "imgs" array only if it doesn't already exist. If a matching element is found, the query will update it. If no matching element is found, it will add the new element to the array.

```
let userQuery = {
  "user.id": req.user.id,
  _id: themeID,
  imgs: { $eq: result.Location }
};

let userUpdate = {
  $addToSet: { imgs: req.body.path }
};

let userOptions = { upsert: true, new: true };

doc = await Images.findOneAndUpdate(userQuery, userUpdate, userOptions);
```

Comment: This looks like a LLM generated answer

Comment: Its work only if there matching value and update ,  I want to add as new one if not match @daniel3380

Comment: I updated the answer, please check it again @Hunter

Comment: MongoError: Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Cannot apply $addToSet to non-array field. Field named 'imgs' has non-array type string

Comment: it suggests that MongoDB is treating the "imgs" field as a non-array field in some documents. This could be due to documents where "imgs" is not an array but a string.
you can use the $exists operator to check if the field exists and is an array before performing the update. If it's not an array, you can convert it into an array and then apply the $addToSet operation. Here's an example:

Comment: Do you need me to write a sample code ?

Comment: Yes please , that would be good for me

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/2a3f-yxAwnG  but I have to update the array , I edited your code but not worked @cmgchess

Comment: @Hunter i meant https://mongoplayground.net/p/G-kP7YBhTEP . by the way to share the playground you need to click share and get a new link. otherwise i dont see edits

Comment: OK I will check , somebody told me to check this page , https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#upsert , what do you think about it ? @cmgchess

Comment: @Hunter do you want to push a value to the img array or create an entirely new document