# Push/Update embeded object in BsonDocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

On below data set, I want to find "*pId*=123" and "*gmData.CarData.cars.oid*='car_1'", if found then update "*gmData.CarData.cars.dt*" with new value, else Push document in "*gmData.CarData.cars*".

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("65a52a03ed163a5b8a06a80d"),
    "pId" : 123,
    "fv" : "1.2.3",
    "gmData" : {
        "CarData" : {
            "cars" : [
                {
                    "oid" : "car_1",
                    "dt" : {
                        "id" : "car_1",
                        "age" : 123,
                        "add" : "add_1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "oid" : "car_2",
                    "dt" : {
                        "id" : "car_2",
                        "age" : 234,
                        "add" : "add_2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "oid" : "car_3",
                    "dt" : {
                        "id" : "car_3",
                        "age" : 345,
                        "add" : "add_3"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Tried so far using**:

```
db.test.updateOne(
    { $and: [{pId:123}, {"gmData.CarData.cars.oid":"car_1"}],},
    {
        "$set":{"gmData.CarData.cars.$[curr].dt":{"id":"car_11","age":1123,"add":"add_11"}}
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [ { "curr.oid": { $eq: "car_1" } } ]
    }
    )
```

Above query is working, if "gmData.CarData.cars.oid.car_1" exists. But I want to perform Push object `.dt":{    "id" : "car_11","age" : 1123,"add" : "add_11"}}` in "*gmData.CarData.cars*", if not exist.

Comment: Is `pId` unique? Are you sure that a document with the requested `pId` exists or do you need to upsert it? Is the cars array always initialized with an empty array or are there documents with an array that is null or missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upsert with MongoDB array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225868/how-to-upsert-with-mongodb-array)

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on an answer without `arrayFilters`.

Here is what i have  :

```
db.collection.update({
  "pId": 123
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "gmData.CarData.cars": {
        "$cond": {
          if: {
            $in: [
              "car_1",
              {
                "$ifNull": [
                  "$gmData.CarData.cars.oid",
                  []
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $map: {
              input: "$gmData.CarData.cars",
              in: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.oid",
                      "car_1"
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this",
                      {
                        "dt": {
                          "id": "car_11",
                          "age": 1123,
                          "add": "add_11"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  else: "$$this"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          else: {
            "$concatArrays": [
              [
                {
                  "oid": "car_1",
                  "dt": {
                    "id": "car_11",
                    "age": 1123,
                    "add": "add_11"
                  }
                }
              ],
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$gmData.CarData.cars",
                  []
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "upsert": true
})
```

It will look for the document with `pId == 123` and update or create the car where `oid == 'car_1'`.

You can try it for yourself on [mongoplayground.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Oe639FA9-C)

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways to solve this:

---

**Update with aggregation pipeline**

The most efficient way is to use a single update operation using an aggregation pipeline (see also @Fourchette's answer). I have also put together a [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bF-P3cwUH4L) that contains a similar aggregation pipeline. In the first stage, the `cars` array is initialized as an empty array if it does not exist yet:

```
  {
    $set: {
      "gmData.CarData.cars": {
        $ifNull: [
          "$gmData.CarData.cars",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Doing this in an extra step simplifies the following stage that upserts the array element using a complex expression:

```
  {
    $set: {
      "gmData.CarData.cars": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $in: [
              "car_1",
              "$gmData.CarData.cars.oid"
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $map: {
              input: "$gmData.CarData.cars",
              as: "car",
              in: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$car.oid",
                      "car_1"
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$car",
                      {
                        dt: {
                          "id": "car_11",
                          "age": 1123,
                          "add": "add_11"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  else: "$$car"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          else: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$gmData.CarData.cars",
              [
                {
                  oid: "car_1",
                  dt: {
                    "id": "car_11",
                    "age": 1123,
                    "add": "add_11"
                  }
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The expression first checks whether a sub-document with a matching id exists; in this case, a `$map` expression maps each array element. If the id of the array element matches the one you are looking for, the `dt` property is updated. Otherwise the original array element is returned.

In case there is no array element with a matching id, a `$concatArray` expression adds the new sub-document to the array.

---

**Multiple update statements**

A simpler approach is to use two update statements: the first statement looks for a document that already has an element with a matching id:

```
db.collection.update({
  pId: 123,
  "gmData.CarData.cars.oid": "car_1"
},
{
  $set: {
    "gmData.CarData.cars.$.dt": {
      "id": "car_11",
      "age": 1123,
      "add": "add_11"
    }
  }
})
```

([mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qARoivSoYOX))

It is important to check the result of the operation. If a document was matched and modified, the following operation can be omitted. Otherwise, you'd issue another update statement - this time checking for the `pId` without a matching `oid` value in the `cars` array. In this case, the new item is pushed into the array:

```
db.collection.update({
  pId: 123,
  "gmData.CarData.cars.oid": {
    $ne: "car_1"
  }
},
{
  $push: {
    "gmData.CarData.cars": {
      oid: "car_1",
      dt: {
        "id": "car_11",
        "age": 1123,
        "add": "add_11"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

([mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p_ZGfepqb8n))

Please note that the second approach is safe against race conditions due to the filters for the update statements. However, it is not as efficient as the update with an aggregation pipeline, but maybe better understandable for team members that are not experienced with MongoDB.