# Updating an embedded array of doucments in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, query-optimization

```
    Shortlist.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            _id: userId,
            "shortlistedPlayers.playerId": { $ne: playerId }
        },
        {
            $push: {
                shortlistedPlayers: {
                    playerId,
                    addedDate: Date.now()
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Simply what i'm trying to do is, find a doucment that corresponds to a userId and then push a playerId in case it doesn't already exist.

This query works fine but i'm thinking that the second part of the filter query which is "shortlistedPlayers.playerId": { $ne: playerId } will make a scan on the whole collection.

Does mongodb find the doucment first and then update the embedded doucment?

Tried addToSet and removed the second part of the filter and it didn't work because mongoDB compares the whole doucment and it's always different because each embedded doucment has a dateFiled and it's always different

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upsert with MongoDB array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225868/how-to-upsert-with-mongodb-array)

Comment: If you think collection scan is a problem, you should build proper index around the fields you used to locate the document for update.

Comment: I don't have a problem with scanning an embedded document, I'm mainly concerned about the behavior of MongoDB when it comes to filtering based on multiple conditions, 
will it first find the document that has userId and then do the $pushing ? or will it check all documents.
I'm new to MongoDB and trying to understand

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the MongoDB doesn't do a scan on each embedded array of documents of the whole collection.
MongoDB first gets the document and then applies the second condition on the embedded document of the specific document MongoDB found.